# How to understand if task on graph-theory has analytical solution?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, induction, extremal-graph-theory

Several Top Secret Objects are connected by an underground railway in such a way that each Object is directly connected to no more than k = 3 others, and from each Object you can get underground to any other with no more than one change. What is the maximum number of Top Secret Objects?

Solution for the task
[image]

So 10 nodes. But is there analytical solution?
I have idea: from one node can come to k others, and from each out of this k else to k others. Thus, number of nodes $= k^2 + 1$. Maybe it's good idea, but I can't prove it for $k\geq2$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we $n$ objects and we have $e$ connected pairs and $e'$ unconnected pairs of objects.

- Then by the Handshake lemma we have $e\leq {3n\over 2}$.
- Now make bipartite graph $H=(P,O)$ where $P$ consist of unconnected pairs of objects and $O$ are simply objects. In $H$ we connect a pair $\{u,v\}\in P$ with object $o\in O$ iff $o$ is connected with both $u$ and $v$.

  Since there we can get fro any $u$ to $v$ with exactly one change we see that each pair $\{u,v\}$ has degree $1$ and since every $o$ is connceted to at most 3 other objects it is connected with at most ${3\choose 2}=3$ pairs in $P$. Since $|P| =e'$ and $|O|=n$ we have $e'\leq {3\choose 2}\cdot n =3n$.

Now we have $${n\choose 2} = e+e'\leq {3n\over 2} +3n$$ and thus $$n-1\leq 3+6\implies n\leq 10$$

---

In general equality case is possible if $$n =k^2+1$$

Comment: I think OP is looking for a generalization to other values of $k$, and it's not immediately clear (to me at least) if your formulas generalize that way. In particular, I'm not sure where $\binom{3}{2}$ comes from for $e'$, and if it should be replaced by $\binom{k}{2}$.

Comment: @Aqua $\binom{n}{2} \leq \frac{kn}{2} + \binom{k}{2} \cdot n$  is the solution for $k \geq 2$ ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks you! But one more question..  
Why in this task there isn't algorithm to find exact value of n (not only upper bound) ?

Comment: But there are at least partial information ho to getthis upper bound. If you want equality case then each object is connected to exactly k other objects. And  every object is connected with exactly ${k\choose 2}$ unconnected objects.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: Hi @Aqua , may I ask how did you get to the the second point where "By the given condition we have e' <= ....." ?

Comment: @ShiranShaharabani I add an explanation.